# How Can I Separate Data Based on One Variable in R?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am still very new to R and currently trying to figure this out. Link to dataset: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AklzhRbnBfwlg24UFaD_6o8UKc5C?e=aEsStP

This dataset includes 9 variables and I am trying to consider only single-birth babies to examine the relationship between the mother's age and birth weight. How can I create a separate data frame from this set that only includes those babies who meet the "no" criteria for the variable "Multiple"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you load the dataset into R, say it is labeled dat, you can write this script.

df<-dat[dat$Multiple=="No",]